# Conditional query in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a combo box on a form that I want to populate with user names.

If the person logged in has an admin role, they can choose any name in the company.  If the user is not an admin, it will only show their own name.

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
If @Role='Admin' then
  SELECT UserName FROM tblUsers
ELSE
  SELECT UserName FROM tblUsers where UserID=@CurrentUser
```

I know how to pass in the parameters for `@Role` and `@CurrentUser`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this query expresses the logic of what you're trying to do.

```
PARAMETERS [current_user] Text ( 255 ), [which_role] Text ( 255 );
SELECT UserName
FROM tblUsers
WHERE
       [which_role] = 'Admin'
    OR UserID = [current_user];
```

However, I'm not sure how you would supply the parameters when that query is used as the row source for a combo box.  You mentioned you have a method to do it.  If that works here, you're done.  If not, I would suggest replacing the parameters with text boxes on the form.

```
SELECT UserName
FROM tblUsers
WHERE
       Forms!YourFormName!txtRole = 'Admin'
    OR UserID = Forms!YourFormName!txtCurrentUser;
```

You can hide the text boxes (set their Visible property to No), and their values will still be available to the query.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a DLOOKUP in the if statement.  You would have to have a control or form property with a username property in order for the following code to work.

```
If DLookUp("role","tblUsers","UserID = '" & Me.strUserID & "'")='Admin' then
  Me.cboUsers.RowSource = "SELECT UserName FROM tblUsers"
ELSE
  Me.cboUsers.RowSource = "SELECT UserName FROM tblUsers where UserID= '" & Me.strUserID "'"  
End If
```